# How to write php code in codeIgniter form helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use same view for edit and create

want to achieve this

```
<form role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form"
                                  action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/leads/saved_call/<?= $leads_details->leads_id ?>/<?php
                                  if (!empty($call_info)) {
                                      echo $call_info->calls_id;
                                  }
                                  ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal  ">
```

by using this form helper

```
 <?= form_open_multipart("leads/Leads/createCall/$LeadDetail->leads_id/if(!empty($call_info->calls_id)){echo $call_info->calls_id}") ?>
```

how can write if condition in codeignitor form helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value in a variable and echo it,

```
 <?php
    if(!empty($call_info->calls_id)){ $cinfo = $call_info->calls_id; } else { $cinfo = '';} ?>
    <?= form_open_multipart("leads/Leads/createCall/$LeadDetail->leads_id/".$cinfo."") 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code:

```
<?= form_open_multipart("leads/Leads/createCall/$LeadDetail->leads_id/(!empty($call_info->calls_id)) ? echo $call_info->calls_id; : ''") ?>
```